# $n$ people form $k$ clubs. Each club has at least 3 people. every two club has exactly 1 member in common. Maximum number of $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

$n$ people form $k$ clubs. Each club has at least 3 people. every two club has $1$ and exactly $1$ member in common. What's the maximum number of $k$?

My thoughts: Similar to oddtown problem, I can think of this as a linear algebra problem. Let $A$ be a matrix of $n$ by $k$ where $A_{ij} = 1$ when member $i$ is in club $j$ and $A_{ij} = 0$ otherwise. $A^TA $ has diagonal greater or equal to 3 and non diagonal entries equal to $1$. What's the biggest dimension of $k$? At the very least $A^TA$ needs to be positive semidefinite. But I can't go any further...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each person $p$ is a member of at most $\lfloor {n-1\over2}\rfloor$ clubs, because removing $p$ from those clubs leaves several disjoint sets of size at least $2$. Therefore, the number of pairs $(p,C)$ such that $p$ is a person, $C$ is a club, and $p$ is a member of $C$, is at most $n\cdot \lfloor \frac{n-1}2\rfloor$. On the other hand, the number of such membership pairs is at least $3k$, since each $C$ contains at least $3$ members. Therefore, we get that
$$
n\cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor\ge 3k\implies k\le \left\lfloor\frac{n}3 \left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2 \right\rfloor\right\rfloor
$$
When when $n\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod6$, the floors disappear, and this becomes $n(n-1)/6$. For these $n$, the bound is exactly attainable using a [Steiner triple system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Steiner_triple_systems) of order $n$. See [Skolem] for the details of how to construct Steiner triple systems for these $n$.

**Edit 2:** Okay, I found this problem in the CRC Handbook of Combinatorial Designs. It is known as a packing design. It turns out that the upper bound $\left\lfloor\frac{n}3 \left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2 \right\rfloor\right\rfloor$ is attainable, except for when $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$, in which cases you can only get that upper bound minus one. The construction for $n\equiv 0,2\pmod 6$ is easy, just take a Steiner triple system of order $n+1$ and delete one person, and all clubs containing them. For $n\equiv 4,5$, you will have to consult the handbook for the construction, in the *Packings* chapter (chapter 40 page 550 in the second edition).

> Charles J. Colbourn and Jeffrey H. Dinitz. 2006. Handbook of Combinatorial Designs, Second Edition (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications). Chapman & Hall/CRC.
>
> Skolem, T. (1958). Some Remarks on the Triple Systems of Steiner. MATHEMATICA SCANDINAVICA, 6, 273-280. https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10551

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have one person be a member of all the clubs and everybody else only a member of one club.  This gives you $k=\lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor$

This paragraph assumes that each club must have exactly three people because I misread the problem.  Otherwise, pick one club and call its members $A,B,C$.  At least two of them, say $A,B$ are members of other clubs.  Call the clubs that include $A$ a-clubs and the ones that include $B$ b-clubs.  No one except $A$ can be a member of more than one a-club and no one other than $B$ can be a member of more than one b-club.  Given that there is an a-club besides $A,B,C$ there cannot be more than three b-clubs (or c-clubs).  Let the second a-club be $A,D,E$.  It has to have one member in common with every b-club.  $A$ is shared with $A,B,C$, $D$ can be shared by one and $E$ shared by another.  By symmetry, there cannot be more than three a-clubs.  We can have $$A,B,C\\ A,D,E\quad A,F,G\\B,D,F\quad B,E,G\\
C,D,G\quad C,E,F$$
for seven clubs at a maximum this way.