# Maximum number of triples from $[n]$ so that no two elements appear together more than once

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer. What is the maximum number of triples from $[n] :=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ one can pick so that no two elements $a$ and $b$ appear both in more than one triple?

So far, I have $\frac{n(n-1)}{6}$ as an upper bound and $\frac{n(n-3)}{6}$ as a lower bound.

For the upper bound, there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pairs of elements whilst each triple contains three pairs (and no pair appears more than once overall).

For the lower bound, the triples $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z$ divisible by $n$ satisfy the condition -- and when counting, for $x$ there are $n$ choices, for $y$ there are at least $n-3$ and then $z$ is fixed (and we divide by $3!$ because of permutations).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What happens for small $n$?

Comment: The result seems to be much closer to $\frac{n(n-3)}{6}$ (but not always attaining this bound) for small $n$.

Comment: This is related to the generalization of [Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem)

Comment: My guess is that this is not known.  Certainly, I do not believe the general problem (fix a subset size, fix an intersection size) is known.  Maybe something special makes this case work, but I do not see it.  DO you have any reason to imagine that this problem has a pleasant solution?

Comment: Not that this proves anything, but see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506585/number-of-subsets-of-size-k-whose-pairwise-intersection-is-of-given-size-j).

Comment: Also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4055728/n-people-form-k-clubs-each-club-has-at-least-3-people-every-two-club-has-e/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is OEIS sequence [A001839](http://oeis.org/A001839).

The formula is
$$\left\lfloor\frac n3\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ if }n\not\equiv5\pmod6,$$
$$\ \ \left\lfloor\frac n3\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor-1\ \ \ \ \text{ if }n\equiv5\pmod6.$$

When $n\equiv1\pmod6$ or $n\equiv3\pmod6$ the maximum families are [Steiner triple systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) and in that case
$$\left\lfloor\frac n3\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor=\frac{n(n-1)}6=\frac{\binom n2}3.$$